# How to verbose VC++ linker output

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

i have no experience in VC++ and I have just started to learn it right now.
I am trying to debug some linker errors so I would like to turn on /VERBOSE and see what's happening. Where do I have to specify the VERBOSE output in VC++ project properties?

Comment: I don't think there is a `/VERBOSE` option. You have the compiler and linker options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options)

Comment: You can add it in Properties->Linker->Command Line->Additional Options. It generates a lot of spam.

Comment: Also Menu :Tools->Options; Projects and Solutions->Build And Run